# Replace commas with underscores between double quotation marks only in sed

Tags: regex, sed

Suppose I have this kind of line

> aaaaa,bbbbb,"ccc,ccc","ddd,ddd,ddd",eee

I want to replace the comma by an underscore, but only within double quotes fields:

> aaaaa,bbbbb,"ccc_ccc","ddd_ddd_ddd",eee

When I use:

> sed 's/(\"[^\",][^\",]*),/\1_/g'

I get

> aaaaa,bbbbb,"ccc_ccc","ddd_ddd,ddd",eee

As you can see, it works for the 3rd field, but for the 4th field only the first comma is replaced. I'd like to tell sed to "backtrack" and "rerun" on the same field as many times as needed to replace all the commas in the field (there can be more than 2...).
I have searched extensively, with no success...

Thanks in advance,
Stephane (my Hello intro has been removed automatically !?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using `perl` for the task since there is an easy way to replace inside matches:

```
perl -i -pe 's{"[^"]+"}{$&=~s/,/_/gr}ge' file
```

The `"[^"]+"` matches chunks of chars between `"` chars, and `$&=~s/,/_/gr` replaces each `,` with `_` inside matches.

You may do that with a GNU `sed`, too:

```
sed -i 's/"[^"]*"/\n&/g;:a;s/\(\n"[^"]*\),/\1_/g;ta;s/\n//g' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/clBnTK).

Here, `s/"[^"]*"/\n&/g` adds a newline before the double quoted substring, `:a` sets a label to keep track of the current match start position, `s/\(\n"[^"]*\),/\1_/g` replaces a newline, `"`, 0+ non-`"`s (Group 1) and a `,` with Group 1 value and `_`, then - if the replacement succeeded - `ta` jumps back to the `a` label position, else `s/\n//g` will remove the intruduced newlines before double quoted substrings.

Comment: I see, you use labels for sed. While for perl it's implicit. I'll probably learn perl one day ! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;s/^((([^",]*,)*("[^",]*",)*)*"[^",]*),/\1_/;ta' file
```

Ignore non-double quoted fields and double quoted fields with no commas and replace the first comma in a double quoted field. Repeat.

Comment: It's been 3.5 years since, but thanks!